# Putting the value of a variable from class to the variable of my form

Tags: vb.net, class-variables

I have a class names `intersection_regular_island` and I created a new instance of it in `form1`. I wanted to re-declare a certain variable in that class so I tried this code

```
Public Class form1
   Dim a As New intersection_regular_island
   Dim penToUse As Pen = a.leftA_pen

   Sub sampleSub()
      penToUse = New Pen(Color.Green, a.arrowWidth)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Whereas if I do it like this, it is working

```
Public Class form1
   Dim a As New intersection_regular_island
   Sub sampleSub()
      a.leftA_pen = New Pen(Color.Green, a.arrowWidth)
   End Sub
End Class
```

Note that it is just a small part of the code, it's not the actual code. It is for illustration purposes so maybe I might missed something.

Seems like I'm missing something that is so simple?

Edit:

I want to do it like that so I can easily perform a `select case`

So instead of copying and pasting this code many times

```
Select Case lightFunctionNum
            Case 1
                a.leftA_pen = New Pen(Color.Green, a.arrowWidth)
            Case 2
                a.leftA_pen = New Pen(Color.Yellow, a.arrowWidth)
            Case 3
                a.leftA_pen = New Pen(Color.Red, a.arrowWidth)
            Case 4
                Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Green
                Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
                If blinkBoolean_A = False Then a.leftA_pen = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean_A = True Else a.leftA_pen = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean_A = False
            Case 5
                Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Yellow
                Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
                If blinkBoolean_A = False Then a.leftA_pen = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean_A = True Else a.leftA_pen = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean_A = False
            Case Else
                a.leftA_pen = New Pen(Color.Transparent, a.arrowWidth)
End Select
```

I wanted it become like this

```
Select Case arrowAndPosition
            Case arrowAndPositionChoices.A_Left
                penToUse = a.leftA_pen
            Case arrowAndPositionChoices.B_Left
                penToUse = a.leftB_pen
            Case arrowAndPositionChoices.C_Left
                penToUse = a.leftC_pen
            Case arrowAndPositionChoices.D_Left
                penToUse = a.leftD_pen
End Select

Select Case lightFunctionNum
        Case 1
            penToUse = New Pen(Color.Green, a.arrowWidth)
            Console.WriteLine("Trigger")
        Case 2
            penToUse = New Pen(Color.Yellow, a.arrowWidth)
        Case 3
            penToUse = New Pen(Color.Red, a.arrowWidth)
        Case 4
            Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Green
            Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
            If blinkBoolean = False Then penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = True Else penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = False
        Case 5
            Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Yellow
            Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
            If blinkBoolean = False Then penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = True Else penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, a.arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = False
        Case Else
            penToUse = New Pen(Color.Transparent, a.arrowWidth)

End Select
```

Comment: You seem to think that `Dim penToUse As Pen = a.leftA_pen` somehow creates a relationship between that variabvle and the property such that assigning to the variable will also assign to the property. That's not how it works. If you expect something to be assigned to that property then you have to assign it to that property.  The second code snippet works because it makes sense while the first doesn't work because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, yeah that's what I'm thinking. I still don't understand what you mean could you give me an example or perhaps a link on how to do that properly? Thank you so much.

Comment: What I mean is that there is no way to do what you apparently want to do. You could do it in a language that supported pointers by using two pointers that referred to the same location but VB doesn't support pointers so you can't.  Why exactly do you want to do this in the first place? There will undoubtedly be a way to fulfil your requirement; just not the way you think.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks sir, I've edited my question so I can explain it in detailed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you not learned about methods yet?  You simply put that second `Select Case` into a method:

```
Private Function GetPen(arrowWidth As Single) As Pen
    Dim penToUse As Pen

    Select Case lightFunctionNum
            Case 1
                penToUse = New Pen(Color.Green, arrowWidth)
                Console.WriteLine("Trigger")
            Case 2
                penToUse = New Pen(Color.Yellow, arrowWidth)
            Case 3
                penToUse = New Pen(Color.Red, arrowWidth)
            Case 4
                Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Green
                Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
                If blinkBoolean = False Then penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = True Else penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = False
            Case 5
                Dim blinkColorTrue As Color = Color.Yellow
                Dim blinkColorFalse As Color = Color.Transparent
                If blinkBoolean = False Then penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorFalse, arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = True Else penToUse = New Pen(blinkColorTrue, arrowWidth) : blinkBoolean = False
            Case Else
                penToUse = New Pen(Color.Transparent, arrowWidth)

    End Select

    Return penToUse
End Function
```

and call that method for the first `Select Case`:

```
Dim penToUse = GetPen(a.arrowWidth)

Select Case arrowAndPosition
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.A_Left
        a.leftA_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.B_Left
        a.leftB_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.C_Left
        a.leftC_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.D_Left
        a.leftD_pen = penToUse
End Select
```

In fact, you wouldn't even have to pass the `arrowWidth` in because you could just have that method return a `Color` and then create `Pen` outside:

```
Dim penToUse = New Pen(GetPenColor(), a.arrowWidth)

Select Case arrowAndPosition
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.A_Left
        a.leftA_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.B_Left
        a.leftB_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.C_Left
        a.leftC_pen = penToUse
    Case arrowAndPositionChoices.D_Left
        a.leftD_pen = penToUse
End Select
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't think of that before. Thanks! Your code helps me sir.